# infinite scroll in angular2 for son data load 75%

Tags: json, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-directives, infinite-scroll

I want to create infinite scroll feature in which initially only first value of JSON data load i.e. the first article should load and after scrolling down till 3/4(75%) part of the page loads the next article at the bottom and the same thing happens with the next loaded articles.
 I am using angular js with rxjs observable :
https://codeburst.io/angular-2-simple-infinite-scroller-directive-with-rxjs-observables-a989b12d4fb1

below is the code:
app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { NewsService } from './news.service';
import { NavBarComponent } from './navbar.component';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [NewsService]
})
export class AppComponent {

 currentPage: number = 1;

  news: Array<any> = [];

  scrollCallback;

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService) {

    this.scrollCallback = this.getStories.bind(this);
  }

  getStories() {
    return this.newsService.getLatestStories(this.currentPage).do(this.processData);
  }

  private processData = (news) => {
    this.currentPage++;
    this.news = this.news.concat(news.json());
    console.log(this.news);
  }

}
```

news.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

const BASE_URL = 'https://www.eremnews.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?minified=true';

@Injectable()
export class NewsService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getLatestStories(page: number = 1) {
    return this.http.get(`${BASE_URL}/news?page=${page}`);
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<ul id="infinite-scroller"
  appInfiniteScroller
  scrollPerecnt="70"
  immediateCallback="true"
  [scrollCallback]="scrollCallback">
    <li *ngFor="let x of news">

     <h1>{{x.title.rendered | json}}</h1> <br>
    <figure style="padding:20px"><img [src]="x.post_thumbnail.thumbnail"></figure> 
      <div class="details">
        <p>{{x.content.rendered |json}}</p><br>
      </div>
      <p>{{x.date_gmt_lang |json}}</p>

    </li>
</ul>
```

In my code, initially, all data is loading at first page.I want to load articles on page scroll down only and in router URL I want to show the id of the article.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that `ul` element has scrollbar as in source code [app.component.scss](https://github.com/ashwin-sureshkumar/angular-infinite-scroller/blob/master/src/app/app.component.scss#L5). `[]` around `immediateCallback` attribute in html.

Otherwise, Compare your code with working [source](https://github.com/ashwin-sureshkumar/angular-infinite-scroller/)

Comment: Infinite scroll is working but initially, I just want to load the 1st article from JSON.Currently, on page load, complete JSON is loading,                                   [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {id: 1135427, date: "2018-01-02T20:02:24", date_gmt: "2018-01-02T16:02:24", guid: {…}, modified: "2018-01-02T20:02:24", …}1: {id: 1135543, date: "2018-01-02T19:55:14", date_gmt: "2018-01-02T15:55:14", guid: {…}, modified: "2018-01-02T19:55:14", …}2: {id: 1135440, date: "2018-01-02T19:48:08", date_gmt: "2018-01-02T15:48:08", guid: {…}, modified: "2018-01-02T19:48:08", …}

Comment: I want to display like below page:                                                                      https://www.eremnews.com/news/arab-world/1127149                                        JSON FILE: https://www.eremnews.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?minified=true